# Eclipse - Arrays cannot be resolved

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, import, helium

I'm using Eclipse Helios with Java 8 JDK. I already did Path thing in System and in program. But this is the only one error i get so far. I can't import Arrays using Ctrl+Shift+O. When i did manualy it give me this error. "Arrays cannot be resolved"

Here is my code;

```
package dizi;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class dizibir {

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            int[] dizi= {1,6,8,3};
            Arrays.sort(dizi);
            for(int i=0; i<dizi.length; i++)
                System.out.println(dizi[i]);

    }

}
```

It's looks like this on Eclipse;

[image]

Edit: After downloading lates Oxygen build it works now. Thank you for all help. Have a nice day. Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse Helios went out (in 2010) way before Java 8 went out. Why do you use such an old, free, IDE. Use the latest version. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)

Comment: The friends might be sharing these old IDE's via storage devices instead of updating or downloading new ones to save some data . :p @JBNizet

Comment: Hello thank you for answer. I just bought a book and this book lesson on this programs. Thats why im using it. If the source of the problem is Eclipse i can swich to NetBeans maybe thanks.

Comment: The source of the problem is not Eclipse itself - it's your _ancient version_ of Eclipse. Get a recent one and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, try to build the path by this way:

1. Right click on project
2. Select BuildPath
3. Select Configure BuildPath
4. Select Libraries tab
5. Then Double clickon JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY
6. Then select alternate JRE

Comment: Hello thank you for answer. My setting already like that. Here: http://i.imgur.com/d7nk7xX.png

Comment: Try to select the radio button (Workspace default JRE).

Comment: Install latest eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Just change the java compiler compliance level like this

> windows-->preferences-->java--->compiler
>   Here is the screen shot 
>   [image: SCREEN SHOT]

Comment: Hello thank you for answer. I checked this before but i don't have 1.8. I don't know why. You can see in here: http://i.imgur.com/IOFexpF.png

Comment: Then install the java8 SDK first on your system and then add it to eclipse in "Installed JREs" (below above "Compiler" settings)

Comment: Install latest eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Your **compiler** compliance **level** of your project (right-click on project: *Properties: Java Compiler*) is **not compatible with** the **Java 8** JRE you are using: <=1.6 vs. 1.8 (your IDE is too old to be able to read the Java 1.8 class file format).

Either install and use an older Java JRE (your very old Eclipse IDE can only handle up to Java 6) or **use the latest Eclipse Java IDE** (recommended):

1. **Download** the latest ***Eclipse IDE for Java Developers*** from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/
2. **Unzip and run Eclipse**

Comment: I just downloaded here too. But i downloaded Helion version. Is that one outdated?

Comment: Yes, Eclipse Helios is from 2010. The latest version is Eclipse Oxygen (June 2017).